# constexpr вызов функции size() у ссылки

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, ссылки, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


template<typename array_type>
auto array_size(const array_type& arr) {
    constexpr auto size = arr.size(); // действительно ли size будет constexpr?
    return size;
}


int main() {
    constexpr std::array arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << array_size(arr);
}
```

Правда ли что в этой программе `size` является `constexpr`, ведь мы вызываем функцию-член `size()` у ссылки? Интересно, что программа компилируется `gcc`, но не компилируется `clang` последних версий. Кто прав?

Comment: Да тут всё правильно по крайней мере у меня работает

Comment: Без указания компилятора такой ответ не имеет смысла.

Comment: Какой стандарт языка вы указывали при компиляции?

Answer (score 2):

Откровенно говоря, мне эта идея - в не-constexpr функции иметь constexpr-переменную - не очень нравится. Вот [такой вариант](https://ideone.com/ftBf5y) мне представляется более корректным и согласованным.

```
template<typename array_type>
constexpr auto array_size(const array_type& arr) {
    auto size = arr.size();
    return size;
}


int main() {
    constexpr std::array arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    constexpr auto as = array_size(arr);
    std::cout << as;
}
```

Так что мне *кажется*, что в вашем случае формально прав clang, но, как обычно, о том, насколько я неправ и как это соответствует стандарту, пусть расскажут гуру :)

Comment: Не совсем понятна логика утверждения "в не-constexpr функции иметь constexpr-переменную". Теперь у вас такая же ситуация получилась в функции `main`.

Comment: @AnT Ну, я несколько раз сказал, что это не более чем мое ощущение :), выделив слово *кажется*. Потому и попросил указать, насколько я неправ :)

Comment: Я об ощущениях и говорю. Интуитивно понятно, что в общем случае вся программа не может быть constexpr. То есть в любой программе, как ни верти, на каком-то уровне будет переход от constexpr к не-constexpr, т.е. на каком-то уровне всегда придется "в не-constexpr функции иметь constexpr-переменную". Вот именно это "ощущение" мне кажется очевидным.

Comment: @AnT Вероятно, вы правы. Но мои ощущения от этого не меняются - по крайней мере, `constexpr` в `main` не зависят от ее аргументов...

Answer (score 0):

Эта программа не должна компилироваться в соответствии со стандартом, так что `clang` прав. Однако в C++23 это станет возможно благодаря принятому [P2280](https://wg21.link/p2280), в котором уберут указанный ниже пункт стандарта.

---

Чтобы объявить переменную `size` со спецификатором `constexpr`, надо инициализировать её с помощью *constant expression*.

[[dcl.constexpr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.constexpr#10):

> ... In any constexpr variable declaration, the full-expression of the
> initialization shall be a constant expression. ...

Однако выражение `arr.size()` не является *core constant expression*.

[[expr.const]/5.12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#5.12):

> An expression E is a core constant expression **unless the evaluation** of
> E, following the rules of the abstract machine, **would evaluate** one of the following :
>
> - ...
> - **an id-expression that refers to a variable** or data member **of reference type** <strike>unless the reference has a preceding initialization</strike> and either
>
>   - ...
> - ...

Здесь E это `arr.size()`, а `arr` является  *an id-expression that refers to a variable of reference type*, не имеющим *preceding initialization*.

Т.к. выражение не является *core constant expression*, то оно не является и *constant expression*.

[[expr.const]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#11):

> **A constant expression is either** a glvalue **core constant expression**
> that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant
> expression (as defined below), **or** a prvalue **core constant expression**
> whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - ...

Comment: ```std::array::size``` является constexpr.
```enum { Test = arr.size(); };``` была бы ошибка, если бы arr.size() был не constexpr

Comment: @Croessmah да, эта функция имеет спецификатор `constexpr`, но это не делает выражение `arr.size()` константным выражением, чтобы объявить переменную `size` со спецификатором `constexpr`

Answer (score 0):

Передача в функцию аргумента с **constexpr** классификатором теряет свою константность в процессе компиляции. И остаётся только обычная константность **const**.
Причина такая, что функция не сможет использовать константность компиляции так как фактический аргумент ему не известен.
Допустим вы сделали шаблонную функцию в заголовочном файле и два **constexpr** массива в двух файлах. Как компилятор может сделать вам код функции с `constexpr size` если размеры этих массивов разные?

h.hpp

```hpp
template<typename array_type>
auto array_size(const array_type& arr) {

// здесь size не может быть одновременно 4 и 5
    constexpr auto size = arr.size();

    return size;
}
```

1.cpp

```cpp
constexpr std::array arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::cout << array_size(arr1);
```

2.cpp

```cpp
constexpr std::array arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << array_size(arr2);
```

*Ни один компилятор ваш код у меня не смог скомпилировать.*